# How many directed graphs of size n are there where each vertex is the tail of exactly one edge?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

In a research problem in an unrelated area, me and a student found it necessary to count the number of directed graphs with every vertex having one outward-pointing edge, with no restrictions on the number of edges pointing inward.

Not being a graph theorist, I was wondering if this is a well-known class of directed graphs.

**Is the number of such graphs for fixed n known?**

If it is unknown or an open problem, we'll work on it together, but it seems likely to be known.

Comment: I'm not sure that we need [digraph] as a tag. But unlike the majority of tags, I'm not sure that we don't need it either (but in either case, I'd think that [digraphs] works better, since most tags adhere to a plural convention). Do you think we need it (in which case, please open a meta thread with this suggestion and why you think it's needed) or do you think that we can remove it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila the singular comes from editing wikipedia, lol. You can remove the tag, though; if it hasn't been created yet, I'm not sure how used it will be.

Comment: Please clarify. (1) Is $n$ the number of **vertices**? (In graph theory, the "size" of a graph is often considered to be the number of **edges**. (2) Are you counting **labelled** or **unlabelled** graphs? That is, do you count $8$ or $2$ of your graphs on $3$ vertices?

Comment: @bof Unlabelled graphs with $n$ vertices.

Comment: Some call such graphs [functional graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest#Directed_pseudoforests), because each one can be thought of as the "graph" of a function $f:\{1, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: These show up in Flajolet & Sedgwick's _Analytic Combinatorics_ text, where they are named as 'unlabelled functional graphs' in accordance with D Poole's comemnt. But they also give them the name "mapping patterns" and cite [EIS A001372](https://oeis.org/A001372) as a reference for the sequence. This includes a number of useful references to the research literature.

Comment: @Semiclassical This gave me all the information I needed. I could award you the bounty if you make this an answer; however, if not, I appreciate you helping our research move forward.

Comment: @BrianRushton: Considering the size of the bounty, I think I'll take you up on that. (Though since I disdain 'link-only' answers, I'll try to include some substance rather than just providing the link.)

Comment: OK, "unlabelled graphs with $n$ vertices". Could you please edit that clarification into the body of the question, as it seems ambiguous the way it is. Also, when you say "outward-pointing edge", do you allow an edge from a vertex to itself? In other words, do you want to count all endofunctions, or just those without fixed points?

Comment: Given the extensive account that Marko has put forth below, I think I'll just be content to have provided that content. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some computational aspects  of this problem that can serve as
a  basis  for  further  exploration. We  present  relevant  generating
functions   and  recurrence   relations  for   unlabelled   trees  and
endofunctions. These basic  data of course cannot take  the place of a
proper investigation using combinatorial methods.

We   have  by   inspection  that   the  combinatorial class   $\mathcal{M}$  under
consideration here is (notation from *Analytic Combinatorics*)

$$\mathcal{M} = \def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{MSET}(\textsc{CYC}(\mathcal{T}))$$
with $\mathcal{T}$ being the combinatorial class of rooted trees.
Therefore the study of $\mathcal{M}$ requires the study of 
$\mathcal{T}.$

We have for rooted trees that
$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{MSET}(\mathcal{T}).$$
This translates to the functional equation
$$T(z) = z \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l)}{l} \right).$$

Differentiate to get a recurrence for the number $T_n$ of rooted trees:
$$T'(z) = \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l)}{l} \right)
+ z \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l)}{l} \right)
\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T'(z^l)}{l} \times l z^{l-1} \right)
\\ = \frac{T(z)}{z}
+ T(z) \left(\sum_{l\ge 1} T'(z^l) z^{l-1} \right) .$$
so that
$$z T'(z) = T(z) + T(z) \left(\sum_{l\ge 1} T'(z^l) z^l \right)
= T(z) + T(z) 
\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} z^l \sum_{m\ge 1} m T_m z^{(m-1)l}\right)$$
which finally yields
$$z T'(z) = T(z) + T(z) 
\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \sum_{m\ge 1} m T_m z^{ml}\right).$$

Extracting coefficients from this we get
$$n T_n = T_n + [z^n] T(z) 
\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \sum_{m\ge 1} m T_m z^{ml}\right)
= T_n + \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} 
\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor(n-1)/l\rfloor} m T_m T_{n-ml}$$
so that
$$T_n = \frac{1}{n-1}
\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} 
\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor(n-1)/l\rfloor} m T_m T_{n-ml}$$
with $T_0 = 0$ and $T_1 = 1.$

This gives the sequence 
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 48, 115, 286, 719, 1842, 4766, 
12486, 32973, 87811, \ldots$$
which is [OEIS A000081](https://oeis.org/A000081)
where the above derivation is confirmed.

Now  return to the  combinatorial class $\mathcal{Q}$  and compute  the generating
function of the operator $\textsc{MSET}(\textsc{CYC}(\cdot)).$

Using the  cycle index of the  cyclic group we easily  derive that the
generating  function  of the  cycle  operator  being  applied to  some
combinatorial class $\mathcal{A}$  is
$$\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}
\log\frac{1}{1-A(z^k)}.$$

Hence the generating function for 
$\textsc{MSET}(\textsc{CYC}(\cdot))$ is
$$\exp\left(
\sum_{l\ge 1}\frac{1}{l} \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}
\log\frac{1}{1-A(z^{kl})}\right).$$
This is
$$\exp
\left(\sum_{m\ge 1} \log\frac{1}{1-A(z^m)}
\sum_{k|m} \frac{\varphi(k)}{m}\right)
\\ = \exp
\left(\sum_{m\ge 1} \log\frac{1}{1-A(z^m)}\right)
= \prod_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-A(z^m)}.$$

It  follows that the  generating function  $Q(z)$ of  $\mathcal{Q}$ in
terms of $T(z)$ is given by
$$Q(z) = \prod_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-T(z^m)}.$$

Differentiate to obtain a recurrence from this:
$$Q'(z) = \prod_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-T(z^m)}
\times \sum_{m\ge 1} (1-T(z^m)) 
\frac{T'(z^m) \times m z^{m-1}}{(1-T(z^m))^2}
\\ = Q(z) \times \sum_{m\ge 1}
\frac{T'(z^m) \times m z^{m-1}}{1-T(z^m)}.$$

Extracting coefficients from this we obtain
$$(n+1) Q_{n+1} =
\sum_{q=0}^n Q_{n-q}
[z^q] \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{T'(z^m) \times m z^{m-1}}{1-T(z^m)}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n Q_{n-q}
[z^q] \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{m}{z} 
\frac{\sum_{p\ge 1} p T_p z^{m (p-1)}  \times z^m}{1-T(z^m)}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n Q_{n-q}
\sum_{m=1}^{q+1} m [z^{q+1}]
\frac{\sum_{p\ge 1} p T_p z^{mp}}{1-T(z^m)}.$$

Now here we need to digress for  a moment to find a recurrence for the
coefficients $P_n$ of
$$P(z) = \frac{1}{1-T(z)}.$$
Differentiating yields
$$P'(z) = \frac{T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^2} = P(z)^2 T'(z).$$
Extracting coefficients we obtain
$$(n+1) P_{n+1}
= \sum_{q=0}^n \left(\sum_{p=0}^{n-q} P_p P_{n-q-p}\right)
[z^q] T'(z)
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n (q+1) T_{q+1}
\left(\sum_{p=0}^{n-q} P_p P_{n-q-p}\right)$$
so that
$$P_n =
\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} (q+1) T_{q+1}
\left(\sum_{p=0}^{n-1-q} P_p P_{n-1-q-p}\right)$$
with $P_0 = 1.$

This yields the sequence
$$1, 2, 5, 13, 35, 95, 262, 727, 2033, 5714, 16136, 
45733, 130046, 370803,\ldots$$
which  is  [OEIS  A000107](https://oeis.org/A000107)  where  a  better
recurrence can also be found.

Returning to $Q_{n+1}$ and using an Iverson bracket we obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^n Q_{n-q}
\sum_{m=1}^{q+1} m [[m|q+1]]
\sum_{p=1}^{(q+1)/m} p T_p P_{(q+1)/m-p}.$$
which yields the formula
$$Q_n = \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} Q_{n-1-q}
\sum_{m=1}^{q+1} m [[m|q+1]]
\sum_{p=1}^{(q+1)/m} p T_p P_{(q+1)/m-p}$$
where $Q_0 = Q_1 = 1.$

An alternate form of this is
$$Q_n = \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} Q_{n-1-q}
\sum_{m|q+1} 
m \sum_{p=1}^{(q+1)/m} p T_p P_{(q+1)/m-p}$$
again where $Q_0 = Q_1 = 1.$

This finally gives the sequence
$$1, 3, 7, 19, 47, 130, 343, 951, 2615, 7318, 20491, 57903, 163898,
\\ 466199, 1328993,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A001372](https://oeis.org/A001372) where additional material awaits and the results of the above calculation are validated.

The following Maple code implements these three sequences.

```
with(numtheory, divisors);

T :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n<=1 then return n fi;

    1/(n-1)*add(add(m*T(m)*T(n-m*l),
                    m=1..floor((n-1)/l)), l=1..n-1);
end;

P :=
proc(n)
    option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1 fi;

    1/n*add((q+1)*T(q+1)*
            add(P(p)*P(n-1-q-p), p=0..n-1-q), q=0..n-1);

end;

Q :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    local res, iv, q, m;

    if n<=1 then return 1 fi;

    1/n*add(Q(n-1-q)*
            add(m*add(p*T(p)*P((q+1)/m-p), p=1..(q+1)/m),
                m in divisors(q+1)), q=0..n-1);
end;
```

**Addendum.**
Note that just for curiosity's sake we can do the labelled 
case es well, which is very simple. Labelled trees are given by
$$\mathcal{T} = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$
which gives the functional equation
$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

The combinatorial class of endofunctions is then given by
$$\mathcal{Q} = \textsc{SET}(\textsc{CYC}(\mathcal{T})).$$

Translating to generating functions we get
$$Q(z) = \exp \log \frac{1}{1-T(z)} =
\frac{1}{1-T(z)}.$$

Extracting coefficients via Lagrange inversion we have
$$Q_n
= n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-T(z)} dz.$$

Put $T(z)=w$ so that $z=w/\exp(w) = w\exp(-w)$ and 
$dz = \exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)$ 
to get
$$n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+1))}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-w} (\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)) dw
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(wn)}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-w} (1 - w) dw
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(wn)}{w^{n+1}} dw.$$

But we have
$$n! [w^n] \exp(wn) = n! \times \frac{n^n}{n!} = n^n$$

and we have just verified the count of the number of
endofunctions from basic algebra.

All of the above (labelled and unlabelled) is already present in some form or other in Harary and Palmer's *Graphical Enumeration.*

**Remark I.** Care should be taken not to confuse the labelled and unlabelled tree functions.

**Remark II.** Care should furthermore be taken in the proper usage  of sets and multisets in the labelled and the unlabelled case. We distinguish multisets and sets in the unlabelled case but in the labeled case the cartesian product that underlies the construction of all combinatorial operators involves re-labeling that uniquely identifies the two components by the choice of labels and there can never be multisets (operator $\textsc{MSET}$), just sets (operator $\textsc{SET}$).

Comment: That is really quite impressive, covering all the relevant bases. I do wonder if there's any more recent results in the research literature, though given the nature of the GF the only thing I'd expect would be more refined asymptotics. (Flajolet & Sedgwing presents specific analysis in that vein.)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Good answer! Very informative! (+1) of course

Answer (score 4):

A beginning:

Let $f:\>V\to V$ be the map defined by $f(v):=$ endpoint of the edge emanating from $v\in V$.

For an intuitive understanding of what's going on here you should consider the iterates $f^{\circ k}$, $\>k\geq0$. Since $V$ is finite each orbit $$O(v):=\{f^{\circ k}(v)\>|\>k\geq0\}$$
must end in a cycle. Call two vertices equivalent if their orbits end in the same cycle. The equivalence classes, together with the connecting edges,  are the components of your graph $\Gamma$.

Such a component has the following shape: There is a final cycle $\gamma=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_r\}$ of length $r\geq1$ if loops are allowed in $\Gamma$, and  $r\geq2$ otherwise. Each $v_i\in\gamma$ is the root of a rooted tree collecting the vertices whose orbits enter $\gamma$ at $v_i$.

I hope that such things can be counted up to isomorphism using Polya counting theory. (The counting of rooted trees is a standard example in this theory. But here the situation is more complicated, since we have necklaces of rooted trees.)

Comment: With regards to Polya, one of the sources cited in EIS A001372 for this sequence is a 1969 paper by de Bruijin [(Enumeration of mapping patterns)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316572900817#), wherein he proves a generalization of Polya's enumeration theorem. The present sequence is given as a special case (page 18).