# Proving $ 2n^{n-3} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{i-1}i^{\ i-2}(n-i)^{\ n-i-2} $

Tags: summation

My question is how to show$$ 2n^{n-3} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{i-1}i^{\ i-2}(n-i)^{\ n-i-2} $$

I got to this result through a problem of counting labeled trees, but when I try to approach actually computing the sum, I've had no breakthroughs.

Comment: Try it by induction, if it helps.

Comment: @Rohan I did, but the sum becomes a mess when incrementing n

Comment: Are you sure there is a $(n-i) $ term? While proving by induction, it comes out to be $0^{-2}$ posing a problem.

Comment: @Rohan yeah, I am, to feel confident in the result, I even simulated the sum for all n under 20

Comment: @Rohan the sum goes to n-1 not n

Comment: Yes, even I saw that, making it invalid to put $i=n $.

Comment: Isn't that very close to the binomial theorem?

Comment: @fleablood the issue is both terms depend on an incrementing variable, and I've tried expanding and manipulating it to arrange it in a way where I could somehow put it in the form, but didn't have much luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by re-writing as follows:

$$2n^{n-3} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} 
{n-2\choose k} (k+1)^{k-1} (n-1-k)^{n-3-k}$$

so that we seek to verify that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
Q_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}
(k+1)^{k-1} (n+1-k)^{n-1-k} = 2(n+2)^{n-1}.}$$

Concerning the exponential generating function for this quantity
$$Q(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} Q_n \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

we observe that when  we multiply two exponential generating functions
of the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that

$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

i.e. the  product of  the two generating  functions is  the generating
function of $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

Therefore  what  we have  here  is  a  convolution of  the  generating
function

$$A(z) = B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} (n+1)^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

with itself.

The combinatorial class of labelled trees has the specification
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\mathcal{T} = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$
which gives the functional equation
$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

Extracting coefficients via Lagrange inversion we find
$$n! [z^n] T(z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} T(z) \; dz.$$

Put $T(z)=w$ so that $z=w/\exp(w) = w\exp(-w)$ and 
$dz = \exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)$ 
to get
$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+1))}{w^{n+1}} 
\times w\times (\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)) \; dw
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} 
\frac{\exp(wn)}{w^n} (1 - w) \; dw.$$

But we have 
$$n! [w^{n-1}] \exp(w n) = 
n! \times \frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = n^n$$
and
$$n! [w^{n-2}] \exp(w n) = 
n! \times \frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} = n (n-1) n^{n-2} = (n-1) n^{n-1}$$
which means that $T(z)$ is the exponential generating function
of $$n^n - (n-1) n^{n-1} = n^{n-1}
\quad\text{i.e.}\quad
T(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Obviously this follows by inspection from Cayley's theorem.

Repeating the  same calculation to  extract coefficients on  $T(z)^2$ we
obtain

$$n! [z^n] T(z)^2 = 
n! \times \left(\frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} - \frac{n^{n-3}}{(n-3)!}\right)
\\= n(n-1) n^{n-2} - (n-1)(n-2) n^{n-2}
= (2n - 2) n^{n-2}$$

so that

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-2} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= T(z) - \frac{1}{2} T(z)^2.$$

Hence

$$A(z) = T'(z) - T(z) T'(z).$$

Observe that
$$z T'(z) = z \left(\exp T(z) + z \exp T(z) T'(z) \right)
= T(z) + z T(z) T'(z)$$
which implies that
$$T'(z) = \frac{1}{z} \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)}.$$

This yields for $A(z)$ that

$$A(z) = \frac{1}{z} \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)} (1-T(z))
= \frac{1}{z} T(z).$$

On seeing this we realize in retrospect that we could have obtained it
by inspection.  Continuing we obtain the coefficient extractor

$$n! [z^n] A(z)^2 =
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+3))}{w^{n+3}} 
\times w^2\times (\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)) \; dw
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+2))}{w^{n+1}} (1 - w) \; dw.$$

We find

$$n! \times
 \left(\frac{(n+2)^n}{n!} - \frac{(n+2)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)
= (n+2) (n+2)^{n-1} - n (n+2)^{n-1}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{Q_n = 2 (n+2)^{n-1}}$$

and we have the claim.

The *labelled tree function* recently appeared at this 
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938519/).

Answer (score 2):

Your result is a special case (setting $x=y=1$, $m=n-2$ and changing to summation index $i=k+1$) of the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m{m\choose k}(x+k)^{k-1}(y+m-k)^{m-k-1}=
\left(\frac1x+\frac1y\right)(x+y+m)^{m-1}\tag2
$$
which in turn follows from a version of [Abel's Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_binomial_theorem):
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x(x+kz)^{k-1}(y+(n-k)z)^{n-k}=(x+y+nz)^n\tag1
$$
The proof of (1) (and the equation numbering I've used) can be found [here](http://people.math.sc.edu/laszlo/abel.pdf), which also explains how to get (2) from (1). The proof, which is rather involved, proceeds by differentiating both sides of (1) with respect to $y$ and then applying induction on $n$. (Maybe you can assume identity (1) is "well known".)

The cited paper mentions in passing a generalization of Abel's Binomial Theorem, known as Hurwitz' Binomial Theorem, and remarks that the simplest proof of the Hurwitz theorem involves ... counting trees. For another angle, see [this](http://www.theoremoftheday.org/Statistics/AbelHurwitz/TotDAbelHurwitz.pdf).